# How can Homebrew print a beer mug in Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app, homebrew

Homebrew has a neat trick of printing out little icons next to its output. Like this:

[image: brew icons in terminal output]

If I copy paste the icon it on its own and hit enter I get the result:

```
-bash: $'?\237\215?': command not found
```

And if I try it with `echo` or `printf` I just `get ????`. Same if I escape all the quotes and `$`s etc.

```
editron:~ stib$ echo $'?\237\215?'
????
```

So how do they do that? What do the magic characters `$'?\237\215?'` mean?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Homebrew is open source, so you can read its code to find out how it shows the icon. The line they're using is in [the file `formula_installer.rb`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb#L266):

```
print "  " if MacOS.version >= :lion
```

The first character in the `print` command is a "", or [unicode #1f37a 'BEER MUG'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f37a/index.htm).

[image]

So it's not an icon but an funny unicode beer mug :)

Comment: Awesome. So in the shell I can just do echo -e "\xF0\x9f\x8d\xba"

Comment: Also, try looking it up in the OS X dictionary (right click > look up) ;)

Comment: Or with octal: `echo $'\360\237\215\272'`

Comment: Also from just about anywhere in OS X you can summon the Emoji keyboard using the shortcut `Ctrl + Cmd + Space`. Doesn't work everywhere but works in most places

Answer (score 14):

BTW, try another variants in terminal:

```
echo $'\360\237\215\270'
echo $'\360\237\215\271'
echo $'\360\237\215\273'
echo $'\360\237\215\274'
```

Comment: For those who do not have a font containing these symbols: These are symbols/pictures of various drinks. See http://codepoints.net/miscellaneous_symbols_and_pictographs